# Synchronizing Threads disables my application's tools

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm using Synchronizing Threads but when the thread is starting i'm not able to click on anthing on my application... but i need to do some work on the app even if the thread timer is on so how can i do that?

note that i'm using vb.net on vs 2010

here is my code:

```
Private Shared thread As New System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(False) 

Private Sub start_btn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles start_btn.Click
    StartTask()
End Sub

Sub StartTask()
    Dim Tpool As System.Threading.ThreadPool
    Dim arg As String = "SomeArg"
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New System.Threading.WaitCallback( _
       AddressOf Task), arg)  ' Queue a task.
    thread.WaitOne() ' Wait for the thread to call Set.
    writeMsg("Thread is done. at ", "list_rpt")
    StartTask()
End Sub

Sub Task(ByVal Arg As Object)
    writeMsg("Thread is starting at ", "list_rpt")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000) ' Wait 4 seconds.
    DoWork()
End Sub

Public Sub DoWork()
    MTProcessTable = selectMtProcess()
    mtCount = MTProcessTable.Rows.Count
    writeMsg(mtCount & " rows selected at ", "list_rpt")

    For Each row As DataRow In MTProcessTable.Rows
        process = New Process_class
        process.id = row("mt_id")
        process.mo = row("mt_mo")
        process.mt = row("mt_mt")
        process.datain = row("mt_datain")

        keyid = validateKey(process.datain)
        MOTable = selectMO(process.mo, process.mt)
        moRowNb = MOTable.Rows.Count()
        MO = New MO_class
        If moRowNb <> 0 Then
            MOrow = MOTable.Rows(0)
            MO.newuser = MOrow("newuser")
            MO.sim_id = MOrow("sim_id")
        End If
        Try
            Select Case keyid
                Case 1
                    If moRowNb = 0 Then
                        If insertMO(process.mo, process.mt) Then
                            writeMsg("1 MO inserted/updated at ", "rpt_txt")
                            message = msgTable.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
                            MsgBox(message)
                        Else
                            writeMsg("1 MO could not be inserted at ", "rpt_txt")
                         End If
                   End if
                Case 2
                    If moRowNb = 0 Then
                        writeMsg("1 process with MO not active and datain 'yes' at ", "rpt_txt")
                        message = msgTable.Rows(7)(1).ToString()
                        MsgBox(message)
                    End if
        Catch ex As Exception
            logFile("executeTimer ----" & ex.Message)
            updateProcessed(process.id, ex.Message, 10)
        Finally
            updateProcessed(process.id, message, 1)
        End Try
    Next row
    thread.Set()
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks to me at the first glance that your thread is busy waiting, can you give us some code or anything? And please specify also your environment a bit, what is your OS what programming language you are using etc.

Comment: yeah well i have to put it on sleep for few sec but how can i fix it? i just need to be able to use my app when i start the thread ..

Comment: thread.WaitOne() ' Wait for the thread to call Set. I think this is the problem, the main thread is waiting for the other to finish, I think that it shouldn't... What is the purpose of such thread sleeping, are you trying to do some work periodically every 4 seconds?

Comment: the problem is that i need to call my function "StartTask()" all over again everytime the thread finishes the work i can remove the sleep i don't need it but i do need the waintOne() because i need to call the function again when the for loop in completed

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't put it in the function that is executed by 2nd thread after DoWork?

Comment: delete:
    'thread.WaitOne() ' Wait for the thread to call Set.
    writeMsg("Thread is done. at ", "list_rpt")
    StartTask()'

insert StartTask() after:

Sub Task(ByVal Arg As Object)
   'writeMsg("Thread is starting at ", "list_rpt")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000) ' Wait 4 seconds.
    DoWork()'

Comment: @cerkiewny can you please tell me how can i stop the trigger when the button stop is pressed?